# Sifting Down From Heap Removal

Tags: c++, heap

I'm trying to work with this heap. I'm inserting a few random numbers then removing them to make sure my heap works. The problem is when I'm removing them I get duplicate numbers that shouldn't exist in the Heap. Pretty much I'll insert the following numbers and get back in return: `5 2 10 10` for some reason.

My main looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#include "heap.h"

int main(void)
{
    Heap<int> inlist(4);
    inlist.insert(5);
    inlist.insert(2);
    inlist.insert(3);
    inlist.insert(10);
    int test;
    while(inlist.remove(test))
        cout << test << endl;
}
```

And my Heap looks like this:

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H

template<typename TYPE>
class Heap
{
    private:
        TYPE* heapData;
        int currSize;
        int capacity;
        void _siftUp(int);
        void _siftDown(int);
        int _leftChildOf(int) const;
        int _parentOf(int) const;

    public:
        Heap(int c = 100);
        ~Heap();
        bool viewMax(TYPE&) const;
        int getCapacity() const;
        int getCurrSize() const;
        bool insert(const TYPE&);
        bool remove(TYPE&);
};

template<typename TYPE>
Heap<TYPE>::Heap(int c = 100)
{
    capacity = 100;
    currSize = 0;
    heapData = new TYPE[capacity];
}

template<typename TYPE>
Heap<TYPE>::~Heap()
{
    delete[] heapData;
    currSize = 0;
    capacity = 0;
}

template<typename TYPE>
bool Heap<TYPE>::insert(const TYPE& dataIn)
{
    bool success = false;
    if(currSize < capacity)
    {
        heapData[currSize] = dataIn;
        _siftUp(currSize);
        currSize++;
        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}

template<typename TYPE>
void Heap<TYPE>::_siftUp(int child)
{
    TYPE temp;
    int parent;
    if(child > 0)
    {
        parent = _parentOf(child);
        if(heapData[child] > heapData[parent])
        {
            temp = heapData[parent];
            heapData[parent] = heapData[child];
            heapData[child] = temp;
            _siftUp(child);
        }
    }
}

template<typename TYPE>
bool Heap<TYPE>::remove(TYPE& dataOut)
{
    bool success = false;
    if(currSize > 0)
    {
        dataOut = heapData[0];
        currSize--;
        heapData[0] = heapData[currSize];
        _siftDown(0);
        success =  true;
    }
    return success;
}

template<typename TYPE>
void Heap<TYPE>::_siftDown(int parent)
{
    TYPE temp;
    int child = _leftChildOf(parent);
    if(child < currSize)
    {
        if((child + 1 < currSize) && (heapData[child] < heapData[child + 1]))
            child++;

        if(child)
        {
            temp = heapData[child];
            heapData[child] = heapData[child + 1];
            heapData[child + 1] = temp;
            _siftDown(child);
        }
    }
}

template<typename TYPE>
int Heap<TYPE>::_leftChildOf(int p) const
{
    return(2 * p + 1);
}

template<typename TYPE>
int Heap<TYPE>::_parentOf(int c) const
{
    return((c - 1) / 2);
}
//**************************************************************************
template<typename TYPE>
int Heap<TYPE>::getCapacity() const
{
    return capacity;
}

template<typename TYPE>
int Heap<TYPE>::getCurrSize() const
{
    return currSize;
}

template<typename TYPE>
bool Heap<TYPE>::viewMax(TYPE& max) const
{
    return false;
}
#endif
```

I'm pretty sure the problem isn't when I'm inserting into my Heap but when I'm removing it.

**EDIT** I changed my _siftDown a bit - now the numbers show up `5 10 3 2`

```
if(child)
{
    temp = heapData[child];
    heapData[child] = heapData[parent];
    heapData[parent] = temp;
    _siftDown(child);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `_siftDown` is broken,

```
template<typename TYPE>
void Heap<TYPE>::_siftDown(int parent)
{
    TYPE temp;
    int child = _leftChildOf(parent);
    if(child < currSize)
    {
        if((child + 1 < currSize) && (heapData[child] < heapData[child + 1]))
            child++;

        if(child)
```

What's that meant to check? `child` is at this point either `2*parent + 1` or `2*parent + 2`, without overflow, since `parent` should always be `>= 0`, that is always positive ~> condition fulfilled.

You need to check whether you want to swap `heapData[parent]` and `heapData[child]`, so that condition should be `if (heapData[parent] < heapData[child])`.

```
        {
            temp = heapData[child];
            heapData[child] = heapData[child + 1];
            heapData[child + 1] = temp;
```

You are swapping the elements at index `child` and `child+1`, that's wrong. You should swap `heapData[child]` and `heapData[parent]` here.

```
            _siftDown(child);
        }
    }
}
```

You also have an error in `_siftUp`,

```
template<typename TYPE>
void Heap<TYPE>::_siftUp(int child)
{
    TYPE temp;
    int parent;
    if(child > 0)
    {
        parent = _parentOf(child);
        if(heapData[child] > heapData[parent])
        {
            temp = heapData[parent];
            heapData[parent] = heapData[child];
            heapData[child] = temp;
            _siftUp(child);
        }
    }
}
```

the recursive call should be `_siftUp(parent)`, otherwise you never sift any item up more than one level.

Comment: Right, I think I added that in my edit portion of my question thanks. I added the conditional instead of just testing child but I still get the output of `5 10 3 2`

Comment: I think this is correct. The output will be `10 5 3 2` which is expected. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your remove method is good while your _siftDown has something wrong.
It's not always true that you siftdown with your left child.

```
void Heap<TYPE>::_siftDown(int parent)
{
    TYPE temp;
    int left= _leftChildOf(parent);
    int right= _rightChildOf(parent);
    int max= parent;
    if(left< currSize && heapData[left] > heapData[max])
    {
        max= left;
    }
    if(right< currSize && heapData[right] > heapData[max])
    {
        max= right;
    }
    if( max!=parent ) //need to sift down
    {
        temp = heapData[max];
        heapData[max] = heapData[parent];
        heapData[parent] = temp;
        _siftDown(max);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It should determine if you need to sift_right here: `if((child + 1 < currSize) && (heapData[child] < heapData[child + 1]))
   child++;`

Comment: @Derp, I haven't yet gone through all you _siftdown code, but I'm pretty sure there's something wrong. I'll figure it out in 5 min

Comment: I did add an edit to my original question that solves a partial functionality of my heap, but it's still not removing in the wrong order so I believe you're right that the removal is the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Derp I think I know where goes wrong. You did check your right child by `if((child + 1 < currSize) && (heapData[child] < heapData[child + 1])) child++;` you mentioned to me. but if this check fails ( left<right), you just go directly to swap while you never check if **left>parent** or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions instead of implementing your own heap:

```
std::make_heap
std::push_heap
std::pop_heap
```

You can find them in the algorithm header

Answer (score 0):

```
heapData[0] = heapData[currSize];
```

Here you should not use `heapData[currSize]` otherwise you are copying the last elemnt of the heap to the top.

For example after removing `5` from the heap `currSize` is `3` and you do

```
heapData[0] = heapData[3];
```

which will create a duplicate of `10` at `heapData[0]`.

Comment: Ah, I see, so do I call my leftChildOf function? The only problem I see with that is that it might not always be the left child I need to sift to.

Comment: @Derp I am not quite sure how your heap is working. You can imagine :). But if you ask me to guess then I think you should do some kind of shifting or move the top of the heap one level down instead of using [0]. But again not quite sure. I am sorry.

Comment: Well what it's doing when it removes is it overwrites what is at  `heap[0]` with the last element in the heap and then sift down from point 0

Comment: @Derp Yes that's exactly what is happening. However for me to figure out how to fix it will take a while because I have to understand what is going on in the rest of the code first.

Answer (score -1):

Without taking a closer look on your code
You realize that test is never initialized?

```
int test; //initialization should happen here
while(inlist.remove(test))
    cout << test << endl;
```

I also do not understand what the purpose of the parameter at Heap::remove(dataOut) is. Would it differ from Heap::remove(void) ?

Comment: Test is initialized. And I'm putting whatever is being removed into `test`

Comment: because Heap::remove(dataOut) return `true/false` indicating operation success/failure while `dataOut` can record which element is removed

Comment: Okay my mistake, I somehow didn't see the & at Heap::remove(TYPE&) ;)